# Why is My Application Crashing When I Call a Method in self.parentViewController?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4

In my code I'm doing the following:

```
-(void)pushCropImageViewControllerWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary {
civc = [[CropImageViewController alloc] init];
[self presentModalViewController:civc animated:YES];
civc.myImage.image = [dictionary objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
```

}

So I have a modal view in my app. When this modal view dismisses, I want to call a method from the parent view (the view that called pushCropImageViewControllerWithDictionary), like this:

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
[(AddNewItemViewController *)self.parentViewController addCroppedPicture:screenshot];
```

}

But it keeps crashing with the following message:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITabBarController addCroppedPicture:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4d15930'

Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong? I am including the header for AddNewItemViewController so the selector should be recognized. Can someone give me a hand on how can I do this properly? Thanks.

EDIT: Declaration of addCroppedPicture:

```
-(void)addCroppedPicture:(UIImage *)image;
```

The implementation itself is empty so far.

Comment: Can you post the declaration for addCroppedPicture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, `self.parentViewController` isn't an instance of `AddNewItemViewController` but the tab bar controller. Hence the crash.

The proper solution is to make a delegate:

```
-(void)pushCropImageViewControllerWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary
{
    civc = [[CropImageViewController alloc] init];
    civc.delegate = self;
    [self presentModalViewController:civc animated:YES];
    ...
}
```

To send a message back to the delegate:

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [self.delegate addCroppedPicture:screenshot];
}
```

It's up to you do declare the delegate protocol:

```
@protocol CropImageDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)addCroppedPicture:(UIImage*)image;
@end
```

And add a property for the delegate to `CropImageViewController`:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) id<CropImageDelegate> delegate;
```

And finally, make your view controller conform to this delegate protocol.

Comment: Alright that solution works for the most part, and I have a question that may be a bit on the dumb side but I really need to know: I don't exactly want viewWillDisappear to be called when the delegate will disappear. I also have a "cancel" button that dismisses the modal view without doing anything. So I can do this without exactly calling viewWillDisappear, right?

Comment: Your modal view controller should have two buttons: "Done" (or "Save") and "Cancel". "Done" will "execute the operation", and then you should associate to it two actions: call the delegate, dismiss the view. "Cancel" means that the user wants to cancel any action, then you must simply dismiss the window to its associated action.

Comment: Yeah, I kept the viewWillDisappear bit in because you used it, but it's better to do it the way viggio24 describes.